# Keeping footer at bottom

Tags: html, css, footer

I've got a little problem. I've placed my footer at absolute bottom, relative to body, but when I'm using a scroll, the footer doesn't stick to the bottom anymore.

this is the HTML

```
    <body>
<div id="top-line"></div>
<div id="header">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="logo"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="menu">
  <?php include 'menu.php';?>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="applybox">
  <form action = "" method = "post">
    <label>Firstname</label>
    <input class="inputfield" type = "text" name = "firstname" placeholder="E.g. Srinivasa" />
    <label>Lastname</label>
    <input class="inputfield" type = "text" name = "lastname" placeholder="E.g. Ramanujan" />
    <label>Age</label>
    <input class="inputfield" type = "number" name = "password" min="16" max="40" />
    <label>Gender</label>
    <select class="inputfield" name="gender">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
    <label>Origin</label>
    <select class="inputfield" name="origin">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option value="Caucasian">Caucasian</option>
        <option value="Asian">Asian</option>
        <option value="African">African</option>
        <option value="Latino">Latino</option>
    </select>
    <label>Describe your character's life up until current age.</label>
    <textarea class="inputfield" name="background" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="The life of your character..."></textarea>
    <input class="applybutton" type = "submit" value = "File application"/>
  </form>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Copyright &copy; 2016 Degenraiderz. All rights reserved.</div>
</body>
```

And this is the CSS

```
    /*===RESET===*/
html,body,p,div,img,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,li,ul,ol,dl,dd,dt,a,form,pagele,td,tr,blockquote,iframe {
  margin:0px; 
  padding:0px; 
  border:0px; 
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing:0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* :focus { outline: 0; }

ul {list-style: none;}

/*=================RESET COMPLETE========================*/

@font-face {
font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Bebas Neue'), url('/fonts/BebasNeue.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sansregular';
    src: url('/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

html {
    height: 100%;   
    position: relative;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #555;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;  
}

#top-line {
    height: 8px;    
    background: #f1ebe0;
}

#footer {
    color: #F7F7F7;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #292c2f;
    height: 17px;
    border-top: 3px solid #f1ebe0;
    padding: 4px 0 2px 0;   
    text-align: center;
    clear:both;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #292c2f;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f1ebe0;
}

.headerbar {
    width: 100%;
}

#navigation {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    text-align:right;
}

#navigation li {    
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

#navigation li a {
    color: #e5e5e5;
    font-family: Bebas, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 17px; 
    -webkit-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    transition: background-color .2s linear;
}

#navigation li a.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f1ebe0;
    background: #444;
    color: #F7F7F7;
}

#navigation li a:hover {
    color: #F7F7F7;
    background: #444;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f1ebe0;
}

#menu {
    width: 100%;
    background: #292c2f;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 7px 21px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.65);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 7px 21px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.65);
    box-shadow:         0px 7px 21px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.65);
}

#menu .wrapper {
    width: 1170px;  
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 1170px;  
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 300px;
    background: url(/images/banner.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#loginbox {
    color: #16325c;
    background: #CCC;
    width: 380px;
    height:300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Bebas, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;  
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}

.input {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    font-family: open_sansregular, Arial, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: all 0.1s;   
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
}

.user {
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;    
}

.pass {
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;    
}

.loginbutton {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #E9D7AD;
    color: #16325c;
    transition: all 0.1s;
    border: 1px solid #999; 
    padding: 12px 24px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: open_sansregular, Arial, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: none !important;
}

.loginbutton:hover {
    background-color: #f1ebe0;  
}

.remember {
    padding: 16px 0;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;    
}

.forgot {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #D8DDE6;
    color: #f1ebe0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

#content {
    font-family: open_sansregular, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
    color: #e5e5e5;
}

#content .wrapper {
    margin-right: -2%;
}

.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 23%;
    margin: 1%;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999; 
    padding: 10px;      
}

.box .content {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999; 
    padding: 10px;  
}
.box .title {
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    background: #666;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-bottom:none;
}

.dropdown-content {
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -135px;
    background: #292c2f;
    min-width: 202px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    padding: 12px 16px;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

nav {
    font-family: open_sansregular, Arial, sans-serif;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-table;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0; 
    z-index: 1;
}
    nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    transition: background-color .2s linear;
}
    nav ul li:hover {
        background: #444;
    }
        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #F7F7F7;
        }

    nav ul li a {
        display: block; padding: 15px 40px;
        color: #e5e5e5; text-decoration: none;
    }

nav ul ul {
    background: #292c2f; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
    nav ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        position: relative;
        min-width: 185px;
    }
        nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 15px 20px;
            color: #fff;
        }   
            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #444;
                border-bottom: 3px solid #f1ebe0;
            }

nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}

#applybox {
    color: #16325c;
    background: #CCC;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Bebas, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;  
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}

.inputfield {
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    font-family: open_sansregular, Arial, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: all 0.1s;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.applybutton {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #E9D7AD;
    color: #16325c;
    transition: all 0.1s;
    border: 1px solid #999; 
    padding: 12px 24px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: open_sansregular, Arial, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: none !important;
}

.applybutton:hover {
    background-color: #f1ebe0;  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/introzen/g88mrg3m/

What have I done wrong here? I've tried putting **height: auto; and padding-bottom: 50px; on Body**, but then on pages not using scroll, the footer is not at bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well its because your body got a `height:100%;`. Because elements height always references to its parents height, it doesn't grow the size you want to.
If you remove the height, the body will calculate its height based on his children.

Remove the `height:100%;` and it will stick to the end of your screen.

If u want to keep the site on at least 100% height, you can use `max-height:100%;`.

Comment: Removing the height from the body makes the body become 0px and make the footer stick to the menubar at the top of the page.

Comment: Actually removing the height makes the body to have `height:auto;` so it expands to the height of his children. In my fiddle your footer is positioned at the bottom. https://jsfiddle.net/g88mrg3m/1/

Comment: Please check how it looks when there is not enough info on the page (no scroll): https://jsfiddle.net/introzen/g88mrg3m/2/

Comment: For that you can add `min-height:100%;` to your body. Then it should work fine ;-)

Comment: Worked like a charm, however when I add padding-bottom: 50px; to the body it shows a scroll at each page...

Comment: Depending on the browser you need an additional vendor prefix to make it work. `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;` However in my fiddle it works nice https://jsfiddle.net/g88mrg3m/4/

Comment: Wow, for some reason I put **border-sizing:border-box;**. No wonder it didn't work. Anyway, thank you for all your help! Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

Change the footer to `position: fixed`

Comment: And in case I would like the footer to be at absolute bottom? (not visible until you're at the most bottom of the scrolled page)

Comment: Then remove the `position: absolute`

Comment: Then it is still not at the bottom of the page when there's no scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Using `flex` your header/footer can grow dynamically and still keep the footer at absolute bottom

In below sample I added a `container` div, removed `position: absolute` on the footer and updated/added these 2 CSS rules

```
.container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}    
.wrapper {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
/*===RESET===*/
html,body,p,div,img,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,li,ul,ol,dl,dd,dt,a,form,pagele,td,tr,blockquote,iframe {
  margin:0px; 
  padding:0px; 
  border:0px; 
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing:0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* :focus { outline: 0; }

ul {list-style: none;}

/*=================RESET COMPLETE========================*/

@font-face {
font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Bebas Neue'), url('/fonts/BebasNeue.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sansregular';
    src: url('/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

html {
 height: 100%; 
 position: relative;
}

body {
 font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 background: #555;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
}

.container {
 height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper {
  flex: 1;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none; 
}

#top-line {
 height: 8px; 
 background: #f1ebe0;
}

#footer {
 color: #F7F7F7;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background: #292c2f;
 height: 17px;
 border-top: 3px solid #f1ebe0;
 padding: 4px 0 2px 0; 
 text-align: center;
 clear:both;
}

#header {
 width: 100%;
 background: #292c2f;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #f1ebe0;
}

.headerbar {
 width: 100%;
}

#navigation {
 list-style: none;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
 text-align:right;
}

#navigation li { 
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}

#navigation li a {
 color: #e5e5e5;
 font-family: Bebas, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 padding: 10px 17px; 
 -webkit-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    transition: background-color .2s linear;
}

#navigation li a.active {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #f1ebe0;
 background: #444;
 color: #F7F7F7;
}

#navigation li a:hover {
 color: #F7F7F7;
 background: #444;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #f1ebe0;
}

#menu {
 width: 100%;
 background: #292c2f;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 7px 21px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.65);
 -moz-box-shadow:    0px 7px 21px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.65);
 box-shadow:         0px 7px 21px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.65);
}

#menu .wrapper {
 width: 1170px; 
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
 width: 1170px; 
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 300px;
 background: url(/images/banner.png) center center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}

#loginbox {
 color: #16325c;
 background: #CCC;
 width: 380px;
 height:300px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 50px;
 padding: 20px;
 font-family: Bebas, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; 
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #333;
}

.input {
 border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    font-family: open_sansregular, Arial, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: all 0.1s; 
 width: 100%;
 padding: 12px;
}

.user {
 margin-top: 8px;
 margin-bottom: 16px; 
}

.pass {
 margin-top: 8px;
 margin-bottom: 16px; 
}

.loginbutton {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #E9D7AD;
    color: #16325c;
    transition: all 0.1s;
    border: 1px solid #999; 
 padding: 12px 24px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: open_sansregular, Arial, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: none !important;
}

.loginbutton:hover {
 background-color: #f1ebe0; 
}

.remember {
 padding: 16px 0;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0px;
 font-size: 14px; 
}

.forgot {
 width: 100%;
 border-top: 1px solid #D8DDE6;
 color: #f1ebe0;
 padding-top: 10px;
 text-align: right;
}

#content {
 font-family: open_sansregular, Arial, sans-serif;
 margin-top: 10px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: justify;
 color: #e5e5e5;
}

#content .wrapper {
 margin-right: -2%;
}

.box {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 23%;
 margin: 1%;
 float:left;
 display: inline-block;
 background: #999;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #999; 
 padding: 10px;  
}

.box .content {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 15px;
 display: inline-block;
 background: #999;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #999; 
 padding: 10px; 
}
.box .title {
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    background: #666;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-bottom:none;
}

.dropdown-content {
 z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
 bottom: -135px;
    background: #292c2f;
    min-width: 202px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    padding: 12px 16px;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

nav {
 font-family: open_sansregular, Arial, sans-serif;
}

nav ul ul {
 display: none;
}

 nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
 }

nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-table;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0; 
 z-index: 1;
}
 nav ul:after {
  content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
 }

nav ul li {
 float: left;
 -webkit-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    transition: background-color .2s linear;
}
 nav ul li:hover {
  background: #444;
 }
  nav ul li:hover a {
   color: #F7F7F7;
  }
 
 nav ul li a {
  display: block; padding: 15px 40px;
  color: #e5e5e5; text-decoration: none;
 }
 
nav ul ul {
 background: #292c2f; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
 position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
 nav ul ul li {
  float: none; 
  position: relative;
  min-width: 185px;
 }
  nav ul ul li a {
   padding: 15px 20px;
   color: #fff;
  } 
   nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #444;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f1ebe0;
   }
   
nav ul ul ul {
 position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}

#applybox {
 color: #16325c;
 background: #CCC;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 50px;
 padding: 20px;
 font-family: Bebas, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; 
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #333;
}

.inputfield {
 display:block;
 border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    font-family: open_sansregular, Arial, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: all 0.1s;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 12px;
 margin-top: 8px;
 margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.applybutton {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #E9D7AD;
    color: #16325c;
    transition: all 0.1s;
    border: 1px solid #999; 
 padding: 12px 24px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: open_sansregular, Arial, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: none !important;
}

.applybutton:hover {
 background-color: #f1ebe0; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="top-line"></div>
  <div id="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="logo"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu">
    <?php include 'menu.php';?>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="content" style="">
      <div id="applybox">
        <form action = "" method = "post">
          <label>Firstname</label>
          <input class="inputfield" type = "text" name = "firstname" placeholder="E.g. Srinivasa" />
          <label>Lastname</label>
          <input class="inputfield" type = "text" name = "lastname" placeholder="E.g. Ramanujan" />
          <label>Age</label>
          <input class="inputfield" type = "number" name = "password" min="16" max="40" />
          <label>Gender</label>
          <select class="inputfield" name="gender">
            <option value="">Select...</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
          </select>
          <label>Origin</label>
          <select class="inputfield" name="origin">
            <option value="">Select...</option>
            <option value="Caucasian">Caucasian</option>
            <option value="Asian">Asian</option>
            <option value="African">African</option>
            <option value="Latino">Latino</option>
          </select>
          <label>Describe your character's life up until current age.</label>
          <textarea class="inputfield" name="background" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="The life of your character..."></textarea>
          <input class="applybutton" type = "submit" value = "File application"/>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Copyright &copy; 2016 Degenraiderz. All rights reserved.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for showing this. However, I used the solution below which was easier and with less code.

Comment: If you are recommending using flex, make sure to inform the people about the browser support. Unfortunately some IE version + Edge doesn't support the flex property. Reference: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: @BasySilver Make sure you check your own facts before commenting, as flex is supported from IE10 _and_ Edge, so its global support today is about 95%

Comment: Oh yeah was a bit confused by the lots of colors. Edge surely supports flex. Anyway in a lot of project its in common to support IE 8+9 so i think its still important to be careful about this.

Comment: @BasySilver Since the OP use box-shadow and transitions he ruled out IE8 and since less than 2 percent use IE9, not much to worry about :)